# crop image with opencv in django project

Tags: python, django, opencv

I want to crop user profile image with OpenCv-python in django and i tried this :

```py
if 'image' in request.FILES:
    img = cv2.imread(request.FILES['image'])
    User = request.user
    width=img.shape[1]
    height = img.shape[0]
    if height> width:
        p = (height - width) / 2
        img = img[p:p+width,0:width]
        User.profile.image = img
        User.profile.save()
    else:
        p = (width - height) / 2
        img = img[0:width,p:p+width]
        User.profile.image = img
        User.profile.save()
        return redirect('profile')
```

I want to crop user image using opencv but i dont know how to save the image after cropping in django

hope you understand and solve my problem .

Comment: You should describe problem yourself!

Comment: I dont understand ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to do it when you actually need to create a new model is to save non-cropped image first, so you can then get absolute image url to crop it.

```py
  user = request.user

  if 'image' in request.FILES:
      user.profile.image.save(user.profile.image.url, request.FILES['image'])
      user.profile.save() # not sure if it's neccessary

      # here you have to pass image absolute url as the first argument
      absolute_url = str(setting.BASE_DIR) + user.profile.image.url
      img = cv2.imread(absolute_url)

      height, width =img.shape

      if height > width:
          p = int((height - width) / 2)
          img = img[p:p+width, 0:width]
      else:
          p = int((width - height) / 2)
          img = img[0:width,p:p+width]

      # now you rewrite image stored in absolute_url
      cv2.imwrite(absolute_url, img)
      return redirect('profile')
```

Also remember to cast variable p into integer, because division can cause float types which then make problems when cropping. Please correct if I made a mistake. Thank you, good luck!